# Multiple Eclipse Projects all tied to one central Git repo....how do I hide parent packages?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

### Scenario:

We have a Git repository that contains all of our Java source code which is laid out in according to it's package infrastructure.I want to refactor all the source code into smaller jars for simplicity and manageability.  Since the Git repo is already being used by several developers, we do not want to redo any of the Git related stuff.

For example consider this layout.

[image]

I want to create 2 new projects that will contain only `class1` code and `class2` code respectively.  When I link additional source in Eclipse (which is the git repo) I can select to exclude `class2` for the `class1` project.

### Problem:

My issue is I can still see temp and anything in it.  I can't make it invisible. It's hard to explain but hopefully someone gets what I'm trying to accomplish here.  I'm trying to reference only one copy of the source without refactoring our entire Git repo.

Comment: Cropping is your friend when it comes to screenshots. I think we only needed to see the upper-left corner.